# Storing access passwords securely in Java code

Tags: java

So, I am planning on making a bit of java code to encrypt and decrypt strings I throw at it. The issue is trying to save the encryption key: It is clearly visible in the Java code and I haven’t found a way around putting it into code. I have also checked several threads here, but I haven’t found the answer to my specific question.

tl;dr
I want to know how to securely store a password in Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tl;dr I want to know how to securely store a password in Java code.

TL;DR - There isn't a way to securely store a password in Java code.

Any password that is embedded in your code in a usable form can be reverse engineered with a modest amount of effort and skill.

The solution depends on the problem you are trying to solve:

- If you are trying to hide and use the secret (e.g. password, key, whatever), AND the user you are trying to hide the secret from controls the execution platform then there isn't a solution.
- If you (or trusted admins) control the platform<sup>1</sup>, AND it is properly secured, then there are a few approaches, of varying degrees of security.  These range from Store the secret in a file that the user can't access through to using an HSM (Hardware Security Module) to hold the secret.
- Refactor the application so that the secret ... and the things protected by the secret are physically separated from the part of the software that the untrusted user runs; e.g. do the "special stuff" on a server.
- Give each user their own personal secret (key, password, etc) ... that can be revoked.

---

<sup>1 - Given that "root escalation" flaws are fairly common, you would be well advised to not allow untrusted users to get access to the platform at all.  However, I doubt that this is an option for what you are trying to do.</sup>